# Relationship Between Topological Closure and Group Generation

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, topological-groups

Let $X\subset G$ be a subset of a topological group $G$.  How are $cl(\langle X\rangle)$ and $\langle cl(X)\rangle$ related in general?  Are there results giving conditions on equality of the two?

Here $\langle X\rangle $ is the subgroup generated by $X$ and $cl(X)$ is the (topological) closure of $X$ in $G$.

Comment: From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_group#Properties since $<X>$ is the smallest sub-group of $G$ containing $X$ and since the closure of a top-sub-grp is a top-sub-grp then if $X$ is not closed then $<X>\subset cl(<X>)$ strictly...  Not sure if this helps..

Comment: Thanks, this I know but it doesn't really help (at-least I don't see how)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't quite understand what condition you're looking for, but I can give a good example in which these groups are the "least equal" as possible. Note that always $\left<X\right>\subseteq \left<\text{Cl}(X)\right>\subseteq \text{Cl}(\left<X\right>)\subseteq G$. Below is an example in which the first and last inclusions are equalities.

Take $G = S^1 = \{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$ with the multiplication from $\mathbb{C}$ and $X=\{e^{2\pi i \alpha}\}$ a point, for some irrational number $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$.

In this case $\text{Cl}(X) = X$ and since $\left <X\right>$ is a dense subgroup of $S^1$ the closure is everything. In other words, on the left side you get just the subgroup generated by $X$ and on the right side you get the entire group.

Comment: Are there general conditions for a topological subgroup to be dense?  (Something like Stone-Weirestrass but without assuming TVS structure or the structure of an algebra)?

Comment: @New_Topologist_On_The_Block I don't think there's something like that for general topological groups. I mean, you can use this one but it's probably not so interesting: The group $N\leq G$ is dense, if and only if for every group $H$ and every continuous homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow H$ which is trivial on $N$ is trivial on $G$. (The proof is simple, because the quotient map $\pi:G\rightarrow G/\text{Cl}(N)$ is a continuous homomorphism). If you know more about the group it might help (for instance if $G$ is locally compact and abelian you can assume that $H=S^1$ - using pontryagin dual)